# SQL Data in Trigger was not Commited : The partner transaction manager has disabled its support

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have created an After Insert Trigger on SQL Server.

```
USE [CSPFContactCenter]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SendSMS_INSERT]
       ON [dbo].[tblSmsSend]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

declare @Text nvarchar(max)
declare @MobileNumber nvarchar(max)

set @Text = (SELECT TOP 1 Text FROM tblSmsSend)
set @MobileNumber = (SELECT TOP 1 MobileNumber FROM tblSmsSend)

exec SqlStoredProcedure1 @Text, @MobileNumber

END
```

The Stored Procedure that will execute in this trigger, want to insert a new record to another database in another server.

I can Run the body of trigger and it work properly:
(I mean this part:)

```
declare @Text nvarchar(max)
declare @MobileNumber nvarchar(max)

set @Text = (SELECT TOP 1 Text FROM tblSmsSend)
set @MobileNumber = (SELECT TOP 1 MobileNumber FROM tblSmsSend)

exec SqlStoredProcedure1 @Text, @MobileNumber
```

But When I use it in Trigger, this exception will accure :

[image]

Thanks for any helping

Edit :
I have Enabled Network DTC Access, but nothing changed

Comment: Don't you think that what `SqlStoredProcedure1` actually *does* is significant? Post the entire code, including `SqlStoredProcedure1`

Comment: Its just insert a record, nothing more. But in another server database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its just insert a record, nothing more. But in another server database

So is 'nothing more' than just a distributed transaction. Which your server explicitly forbids, as the message clearly indicates.

When you run the `exec SqlStoredProcedure1` on its own you do not create a distributed transaction as you did not start a local transaction. By contrast when running from a trigger you always *must* be already enrolled in a local transaction which therefore must escalate to a distributed transaction.

There is no solution. Either talk to the administrator of the remote server to allow distributed transaction (I for one would not allow this in his place) or, better, design a solution that does not involve remote servers. Use replication or service broker instead.